# Call a method in the ViewModel Programatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have A and B ViewModels, and I add a click button to call a method. However, I wonder how could I call it programatically without clicking on the button

**AViewModel.cs**

```
public IMvxCommand BSelectedCommand => new MvxCommand<BViewModel>(BSelected);

public void BSelected(BViewModel bViewModel)
{
    if (bViewModel != null)
    {
       SelectedStudents = bViewModel;
       bViewModel.IsSelected = true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why can't you just call `BSelected`?

Comment: `BSelected` looks for a parameter - `bViewModel`?, but how `ICommand` calls it without passing paramater?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking.

Comment: It's hard to tell because it's unclear what BViewModel is in your example.

Comment: I need to call `BSelected()?` or `BSelected(bViewModel)`. I am asking because `MvxCommand<BViewModel>(BSelected)` passing `bViewModel`

Comment: Because you have "BViewModel bViewModel" as parameter you need to pass something of type BViewModel. You could pass null but you have a null check in your method. If you have a field called bViewModel as your comment suggests BSelected(bViewModel); would call the method, yes

Comment: how can I call `IMvxCommand BSelectedCommand` programatically?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this framework but usually you have something like BSelectedCommand.Execute(); but as you noticed you need to pass BViewModel. Also if you call the command instead of the method you need to pass that. Maybe you are looking for BSelectedCommand.Execute(new BViewModel()); this would pass a NEW BViewModel object. You need to share more code if that doesn't answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I assume IMvxCommand has a method called "Excute(BSelected)" - it would be a typical MVVM command object then. In which case you

```
AViewModel avm = new AViewModel();
avm.BSelectCommand.Execute(new BViewModel());
```